# What is the difference between "fallen" and "stürzen"?

Tags: word-usage, verb

What is the difference between these two words for "fall"?  On a website I read the following:

> Halten Sie das Baby immer so sicher, daß es auf keinen Fall **stürzen** kann.

Would the word "fallen" also work here?

Comment: could you please provide us with the link to that website in order for us to see the context? Is the baby in the arm of the adult?

Comment: Yes, the baby is in the arm of the adult as indicated by "Halten Sie das Baby..."

Answer (score 6):

**Stürzen** is mostly used in connection with human beings...

> *Sie ist die Treppe hinunter gestürzt.*
>
> *Ich bin letzte Woche vom Fahrrad gestürzt*.

**Fallen** can be used for various kinds of things, while the verb appears quite often with a prefix attached to it such as **hinfallen** (synonym for stürzen), **umfallen** (to fall over or to collapse),...

> *Sei vorsichtig, dass du nicht hinfällst.*
>
> *Die Mülltonne ist durch den Windstoß umgefallen.*

(Ps: 'daß' is no longer used, please use the new spelling 'dass' instead)

Comment: To me, _hinfallen_ would mean that the baby stood on its own feet before the fall. Here, I think, it is on the arm of some adult, and I’d use _herunterfallen_ etc.

Comment: And regarding _dass_ vs. _daß_, if this is quoted from some website, you see that it is in fact still used. Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/751/should-i-use-the-old-spelling-rules

Comment: I would agree with you that *herunterfallen* sounds definitely best. That sentence did sound odd to me from the beginning... :)

Comment: Not sure why the sentence would sound odd.  As far as I know, it was written by a native speaker.  It's from a German website that deals with "schwangerschaft, geburt und baby".  http://www.baby-welten.de/das-neugeborene/baby-halten-und-hochnehmen/

Comment: Interestingly, it does spell _dass_ in new orthography. :-) – Even native speakers don’t always find the best expressions. Here, it only sounds somewhat strange, but not “definitely wrong”.

Comment: @ kokirii well... I guess you could say it that way... I would just not use it. Personally, I would use 'stürzen' when I sit on a bike or stand on my feet and then fall... Maybe it's a dialectal thing...?!?

Comment: @chirlu: I think only older people who learned 'daß' at school and are reluctant to accept the "Neue Rechtschreibung' still use the old orthography :) Younger people, newspapers and newly printed text  should use 'dass'...

Comment: lol well...I'm a younger person but I started my German studies in college about 8 years ago and just got used to writing daß...time to change, I guess!

Comment: yepp, I think it's time to change :) but it's never too late, you might want to have a look at the top of page 6 http://www.duden.de/sites/default/files/downloads/Duden_Die_neue_deutsche_Rechtschreibung_kurz_gefasst.pdf

Comment: @rena: I am one of those older people then, I guess (I’m 33). :-) I do know both orthographies (for the corner cases, I at least know when to start looking something up, and I own dictionaries from pre-reform, mid-reform and post-reform, as well as from 1960), but for what I write I prefer a “modified old orthography”. I’m not going to change this. And I don’t like to be told that it’s “wrong”. ;-) – Still, I agree that new learners should probably learn the new orthography. It’s “gekommen um zu bleiben”.

Comment: Die SPD nicht vergessen, die regelmäßig umfällt.

Comment: Übrigens: Die Regierung stürzen, den Kuchen stürzen - wie kommt man darauf, dass stürzen v.a. im Zusammenhang mit Menschen benutzt wird? Gibt es dazu Studien?

Answer (score 4):

`fallen` has the most general meaning, that's why it's used in physics: `freier Fall`=`free fall`.

`stürzen` is used for falls including other movements or forces:

> Die Treppe hinunterstürzen. ⇒ Several rolls are included.
>
> Sturzflug. ⇒ The animal or airplane is even accelerating the fall by itself.
>
> Den Kuchen stürzen. ⇒ One half roll or an acceleration and a stop are included.

`stürzen` can regionally also have the general meaning of `fallen`.

`hinfallen`, `umfallen`, `herunter fallen` and `herab fallen` specify some aspects of the fall:

- `hinfallen`: short fall out of a movement to a drob on the ground
- `umfallen`: fall from standing to lying
- `herunter fallen`, `herab fallen`: fall downward (tautology, because all falls go downward)

From these, only `herunter fallen` and `herab fallen` are suitable, but `herab fallen` is not used in this context.

Conclusion:

`fallen` (see chirlu's answer) and `herunter fallen` are the best alternatives. `stürzen` would only regionally be used. An alternative construction would be:

> Halten Sie das Baby immer sicher und lassen sie es nicht/auf keinen Fall (herunter) fallen.

Comment: Nix Tautologie. Du bist doch bestimmt schon mal eine Treppe "hochgefallen" ;)

Answer (score 3):

One reason not to use *fallen* here: The combination “… auf keinen Fall fallen …” sounds strange due to the repeated syllable. Apart from this, it is probably acceptable in your sentence, although I would prefer *herunterfallen* over both *fallen* and *stürzen*.

Where the denotations of *fallen* and *stürzen* overlap, I think *fallen* is more neutral, whereas *stürzen* suggests that the fall was unintentional and dangerous. Both verbs have additional meanings where they can’t be interchanged. Also, *fallen* can never be used as transitive verb.

## stürzen

- to hurry:

  > Sie stürzte nach Hause.
- to cause sth. to fall, to upend (also figuratively):

  > Sie stürzten die Statue von ihrem Sockel.
  >
  > Sie wollten den Präsidenten stürzen.
- to turn out the cake:

  > Den Kuchen stürzen und mit Puderzucker bestreuen.

For some reason, you can’t use *fallen* here:

> Sie ist mit dem Fahrrad/mit dem Motorrad gestürzt.

## fallen

- to decline:

  > Die Arbeitslosenzahlen fallen weiter.
- to be killed in action:

  > Mein Großvater ist im Zweiten Weltkrieg gefallen.

Comment: Die Aktienkurse stürzen in den Keller. Dass die Arbeitslosenzahlen es diesen nicht gleich tun liegt an der Konjunktur - nicht an der dt. Sprache. Und mit Fahrrad/Motorrad kann man m.E. sehr wohl fallen. Stürzen aber betont den Überschlag, das rotieren um die eigene Achse wie beim Pudding.

Comment: @user unknown, stürzende Zahlen: Das geht nicht ohne einen Zusatz wie _in den Keller_, _ins Bodenlose_. Das weist darauf hin, daß es immer noch als Bild verstanden wird, wenn auch ein recht blasses. Im Unterschied z, u _fallen_, wo es sich zu einer neuen Bedeutung entwickelt hat.

Comment: @user unknown, Zweiräder: Für einen Fahrradsturz braucht man keinen Überschlag. 90 Grad zur Seite reichen völlig aus. Ansonsten kann man zwar _vom_ Rad fallen oder mit dem Rad aus dem Fenster fallen, aber für einen gewöhnlichen Sturz kann man nicht _fallen_ sagen.

Comment: Dass Aktienkurse in den Keller stürzen können, aber Temperaturen nicht einfach so, halte ich für eine ad-hoc-Erfindung deinerseits, die durch nichts gerechtfertigt wird außer Deinem Wunsch Recht zu behalten. Und wenn man mit dem Rad um 90° zur Seite kippt ist das eine Rotation um eine Achse - (nicht die eigene, das war falsch und nehme ich zurück). Überschlag meint auch nicht eine 360° Rotation, bevor dieser Einwand kommt...

Answer (score 1):

`fallen` is neutral as a matter of fact. `Stürzen` has a negative connotation, e.g. reasoned by accident and with an unexpected speed.

Comment: At first glance this is true but I think it's much more complicated. The word, however, itself is not necessarily negative. Though, you might use this word to imply a stronger impact.